# Can move windows out of desktop in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10

Today I installed Ubuntu 17.10 and currently I am trying to use it with 4 displays in the following orientation:
[image: orientation of the displays]
The problem is that I can move windows outside of my screen into the red area, so I cannot see them anymore. Especially it is impossible to maximize the windows through moving them to the top of the screen, which is very annoying. Does anyone have a solution to that problem?

With my old Ubuntu 14.04 it was possible to define the displays in the compiz settings to get it working correctly, but  in 17.10 the compiz settings are changing nothing...